# Nginx and Gunicorn with Docker - How to limit access to Flask app to only nginx?

Tags: python, docker, nginx, flask

My current Flask and Docker setup is the following:

[image: Current Flask with Docker Setup]

In this scenario, end users access the application container from the external IP on port 80 (which is a request to the Nginx container), which then proxies the request over to application container running on port 8000 with Gunicorn. However, people can bypass Nginx by using the same URL, but specifying the port as 8000, accessing the app directly using Gunicorn.

How do I limit access to my Flask application so it is only accessible via the Nginx container? If I block port 8000 in my server's firewall, would Nginx still be able to proxy to the container running on port 8000?

Comment: How do you organize containers? Do you use docker-compose?

Comment: Since this is a basic "Hello World" style app, I am just using two Dockerfiles (one for my app and one for nginx, the nginx one in a subdirectory), and build them seperately, but I can change this to a docker-compose.yml if needed.

Answer (score 2):

If you `--bind=127.0.0.1:800` ([doc](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/run.html)) then `gunicorn` should be limited to the (docker) host.

You should test this to confirm.

Comment: That sounds right, but wouldn't that be limited to the operating system on the Docker container? Considering it's containerized, this would open port 8000 on the container, but the other Nginx container wouldn't be able to access it because the specific IP of the app container isn't exposed, right?

Comment: I was unclear as do how you're running the containers. The text suggests 2 containers but the diagram suggests a composite. IIRC Docker Engine only exposes containers to the host's localhost interface

Comment: Yes, sorry if I was unclear, I am running two containers, one for Nginx and one for my application (which runs on gunicorn). Requests come into the Nginx container, which are then forwarded to the separate container that runs my app.

Comment: Additionally, to clear things up: the diagram shows the nginx container and the "myapp" container both running in the Docker Engine, which is running on my backend machine.

Comment: I mentioned this in the other answer, but implementing this also resulted in a "Connection Refused" error in the Nginx logs.

Answer (score 1):

Use communication across links. Links allow containers to discover each other and securely transfer information about one container to another container. When you set up a link, you create a conduit between a source container and a recipient container. The recipient can then access select data about the source. To create a link, you use the --link flag.

First start you app.

```
docker run -d --name my_app APP_IMAGE
```

Then start nginx container with link to your app container.

```
docker run -d -P --name nginx --bind=YOUR_NGINX_BIND --link my_app:my_app NGINX_IMAGE
```

Your application is now accessible from your nginx container via the alias "my_app" (no ip address needed). It will not be available from the host.

More info: https://docs.docker.com/network/links/#communication-across-links

Comment: This seems like the correct solution, but using bridge networks instead of the legacy --link method. But what happens if there are 2 instances of the "myapp" container, and one instance of nginx, all connected? Which container will nginx proxy to - instance 1 or instance 2?

Comment: In your question, you wrote that you have "one nginx and one application." Use docker-swarm or kubernetes to use a load balancer between peer instances of the application.

Comment: I get it now, thanks. As a side question: in the other answer, it specifies to simply run the container on whatever port (8000 in my case) without using the -p option (or, as an alternative, run the gunicorn on localhost instead of 0.0.0.0). Is there any reason you recommended network links over that method?

Comment: This is the principle of docker, only nginx (reverse-proxy) container "sees" the app. 
There is no reason for access from the "host". After all, it is the main sense to do a reverse-proxy so that the app itself is hidden behind the proxy layer. If you do this directly via port 8000 on the host, then it makes no sense to have a reverse-proxy there, as the app will also be available directly. And if you also mentioned load balancing, it would also be difficult to do that, because you would not have all instances of the app released on port 8000. I hope I made it a little clearer.

Comment: So my understanding is that your answer leaves the container only accessible to the nginx container, and nothing else, whereas the other answer leaves it accessible to the nginx container and the localhost 127.0.0.1 ip, and nothing else. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Basically it doesn't matter if you only do it in a development environment. But the solution with container relinking is preferred for production. And as I mentioned above, it's ready for multiple instances and scaling.

Comment: I tried to implement this, but I keep getting a "Connection Refused" error in the Nginx logs.